# How can I generate same row multiple times?

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I am trying to make a sticker using jasper report.

below image shows the structure.
[image]

I am passing a query to generate jasper report.
I have design the above structure in 'detail field' of jasper report so it can't repeat ,now I need to generate my query-result multiple times.

which means if currently my query gives me below result:-

[image]

I wish to produce the same result n times.

So If my query repeats the same row n times then it will automatically generate this structure 4 or n times

So anybody knows how to repeat the same row in mysql result query or anybody have better solution than this to do this job.

my expected result is as below
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: hi tobi6
I have edited my question,Can you check now.

Comment: Extend the detail band and copy/paste it three times. Since the database is only giving one row, the report should handle the multiplication.

Comment: but it is not fixed that I want it only 4 times only,it may change, that count may be decrease or increased.

Comment: Ok. Then the best way is possibly to create a SQL which multiplies the result according to a parameter. Also it might be possible with a bean in which one result is multiplied several times.

Comment: I have edit the title to be more generic, if you do not like it feel free to rollback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying query is one solution example by using union

```
SELECT REPEAT('a',1) UNION SELECT REPEAT('b',10);
```

but I will give you a pure jasper-reports solution, defining a parameter that indicates how many times your print should be repeated

> The pure jasper reports solution is using a subreport, passing an
> `JREmptyDatasource(nrOfPrints)` and the fields as parameters. The subreport will repeat the detail band as many time as the `nrOfPrints` and you can output the parameters (your main report fields) in it.

### Example

**Main report**

The parameter that defines how many times to repeat is `RepeatNumber` also see how I pass the fields as parameter to the subreport, you need to pass all your fields.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="RepatDataSource" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ceca1b98-d43c-4ee0-8339-661aa2ea53a9">
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\jdd\\projects\\StackTrace\\jasper\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="RepeatNumber" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[3]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[Your query]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="field1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="100" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="100" uuid="9d56da00-c1c9-4b2b-94e2-4019e4f58c8f"/>
                <subreportParameter name="NR_REPEAT">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{RepeatNumber}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="field1">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource($P{RepeatNumber}.intValue())]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "RepatDataSource_subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Subreport**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="RepatDataSource_subreport" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="98ddead4-e116-4c91-9ecb-416c10c3065c">
    <parameter name="NR_REPEAT" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="field1" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="108" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="328" y="1" width="100" height="20" uuid="c5642fd7-9f63-4aa5-8503-16b1388c156b"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} + "/" +$P{NR_REPEAT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="45" y="35" width="125" height="20" uuid="5c2bb49a-ba95-4cb7-8c46-c32a0769e5e9"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{field1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="1" uuid="dd3e7e6c-979e-421b-9f71-479e64c8023b"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="35" width="45" height="20" uuid="0443e2f4-25bd-4837-9c95-bca2b26b3996"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="214" y="1" width="114" height="20" uuid="0e20ec29-0092-41a3-b977-f8f64ff842ea"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Print Educational Books]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output** (with 1 record from my database)

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks Petter Friberg,sorry for late reply, I am working on your pure jasper-reports solution ,and I think it will work for me.
Can you explain your second solution by using query please,?
If my query is

       "select * from abc where id =1" 

how do I repeat this row.?

Comment: understood the REPEAT() solution also,Thank You Petter Friberg

Comment: @JayshreeKharate the REPEAT was just example the keyword is UNION, but maybe there is a better way to do it in your query (but there is not enough info in question), however the pure jasper solution from performance issues is probably faster (you need to load less data from network), the only draw back is that you need to pass all fields as parameters

Comment: Yes I also find the  pure jasper solution reliable.